# Removing Values From An Array When CheckMarked

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to remove the values of an array when they are check marked.

My HTML

```
<ul id="keyWords">
  <li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">thirteen</li>
  <li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">twelve</li>
  <li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">eleven</li>
  <li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">ten</li>
  <li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">nine</li>
  <li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">eight</li>
  <li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">one</li>
</ul>
```

When this button is clicked i need the check marked values to be removed from the array

```
<button id="clearChecked">Clear Checked Items</button>
```

And this is the jquery function I am trying to use but it is not working. 
i need the function to remove the checked boxed values from the array named `localArray` and the keywords are in the `ul` of `keyWords`

```
$('#clearChecked').click(function() {
  var keyWords = $('#keyWords').html();
  if ((index = keyWords.indexOf($(localArray.this).val())) !== -1) {
    localArray.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    if ($(keyWords.this).is(':checked')) {
      localArray.push($(this).val());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: could you post the contents of the `localArray` ?

Comment: They are posted in the question. but they can be anything. at anytime.

Comment: localArray is the array that is populating the html i showed in the question.

Comment: You mean to say, each entry in the array is `<li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">thirteen</li>` !? or is it just the string `thirteen` ? Since checkbox does not have any value associated as per the html snippet that you have provided.

Comment: no. the array is one [two], [three], I am appending the html to the array values when I print them to the screen

Comment: You should add the array entry as value/data/some custom attribute to the input textbox when you are appending the html to.. that way you have an easy way to remove  items from array. or follow the answer that @Axel Amthor provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with splicing the array, just create a new one:

```
var newArray = [];
$('#clearChecked').click(function() {
  $('#keyWords > input').each( function (n, obj) {
      if ($(obj).is(':checked')) {
          newArray.push($(obj).val());
      }
  }
});
localArray = newArray;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. You make it sounds so easy. It didn't work exactly but the logic is what i needed. I appreciate it.
but isnt your function saying if they are checked push to the new array?

Comment: @NichoDiaz yes, that's the principle.

Comment: Ya but if it is checked I want to delete it. not keep it. The point is they can remove values from the array by checking them and clicking clear

Comment: But that's only negating the condition: `if ( ! $(obj).is(':checked') ) {` and you get the inverse new array

Answer (score 0):

Each time you click locale override localArray, more clever than to remove objects from it

```
<ul id="keyWords">
    <li><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value='thirteen'>thirteen</li>
    <li><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value='twelve'>twelve</li>
    <li><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value='eleven'>eleven</li>
    <li><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value='ten'>ten</li>
    <li><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value='nine'>nine</li>
    <li><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value='eight'>eight</li>
    <li><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value='one'>one</li>
</ul>
<button id="clearChecked">Clear Checked Items</button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var localArray = [];
$('#clearChecked').click(function() {
    var Array = [];
      $('#keyWords input').each( function () {
         if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            Array.push($(this).val());
      });
    localArray = Array;
    console.log(localArray);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Each time you click locale override localArray, more clever than to remove objects from it.